# How do I use the built-in function Interpolation for a simply linear interpolation?

Tags: functions, interpolation

my situation is as follows: I have 2 points on the plane {1,1} and {2,4} I would like to fit a linear function y = ax+b through those points. I used the Interpolation function below, but there is an "error" saying "Interpolation: Requested order is too high; order has been reduced to {1}" . What does that mean ? Did I use the right built in function for the linear interpolation ?

```
Interpolation[{1, 1}, {2, 4}]
```

Comment: Read the docs more carefully: `Interpolation[{{1, 1}, {2, 4}}]` or `Interpolation[{{1, 1}, {2, 4}}, InterpolationOrder -> 1]`.

Comment: opps, thanks Michael

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative answer, why not just directly fit your data?

```
 Fit[{{1, 1}, {2, 4}}, {1, x}, x]
 (*-2. + 3. x*)
```

Comment: `InterpolatingPolynomial[]` is more appropriate: `InterpolatingPolynomial[{{1, 1}, {2, 4}}, x] // Expand`